# Объединение кода в один файл

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Проблема вот в чем:
Есть 2 кнопки на одной странице,при клике на каждую их кнопок идет ajax запрос и вывод,допустим это выглядит сейчас так

```
$(".btn1").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: "categ=" + categ,
      url: "serverscript/page1.php",
      success: function(data) {
       $(".block1").html(data);

      }
  });
```

**page1.php**

```
include './config.php';
$categ=$_REQUEST['categ'];
$STH = $DBH->query('SELECT * from table1 where  categ= "' . $categ. '"   ');  
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   
while($row = $STH->fetch()) {  
echo $row{'name'}
}
```

И примерно тоже самое у 2 кнопки

```
 $(".btn2").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          data: "categ2=" + categ,
          url: "serverscript/page1.php",
          success: function(data) {
           $(".block2").html(data);

          }
      });
```

**page2.php**

```
include './config.php';
$categ2=$_REQUEST['categ2'];
$STH = $DBH->query('SELECT * from table1 where  categ2= "' . $categ2. '"   ');  
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   
while($row = $STH->fetch()) {  
echo $row{'name'}
}
```

Примерно как то так,вопрос в чем,как я могу создать 1 файл `php` и делать ajax запрос на определенный кусок кода,как то в функции обернуть что ли.
Что бы не делать 2 файла page1 и page2, а замутить 1 где эти оба куска.Надеюсь Вы меня поймете

Comment: нужно чтоб в базе была таблица `category` с категориями, а в таблице столбец `category_id` указывающий на таблицу с категориями....и тогда запрос сведется к запросу `SELECT * from table1 where  category_id = $id;` .... и если будут прибавляться категории не придется писать `caeg2`, `categ4` и прочей чепухи.....а еще интересно - в чем смысл использования PDO без подготовленных переменных?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский,  да не,это абсолютно абстрактный код,я его на ходу придумал ,суть вопроса как вообще объединить все в один файл и обращаться к конкретной  функции или куску кода

Comment: В таком случае придется целую статью писать про классы и маршрутизацию....